# Is there a method available to store a file in mongo under a specific directory

Tags: pymongo, gridfs, multer-gridfs-storage

I need to maintain a file system in mongo where I need directories to be created and file should be placed in the directory which i have created. So is there any in built functionality in python or how we can do that using GridFs?. So basically along with uploading the file i need to mention the directory where it needs to be placed

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! Please read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please also read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GridFS permits specifying the name of the file. You can put anything you like in there including a path where components are separated by slashes so that it looks like a filesystem path.

However, GridFS does not provide any facilities for hierarchical traversal of stored files (i.e. grouping files into directories). You'd have to implement that in your own application/library if you need this functionality.